# Initializing data in a gorm data model

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-2.0

I have the following domain layer:

Product:

```
@Resource(uri='/product')
class BasicProduct {

    String title
    String description
    Double price

    Date dateCreated 
    Date lastUpdated 

    static hasMany = [tag : Tag]

    static constraints = {
        title(blank: false, unique: true)
        description(blank: false)
        price(blank: false)//, inList: [5.0,15.0,25.0,50.0,100.0])
    }

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
      }

}
```

Tags:

```
@Resource(uri='/tag')
class Tag {

    String title

    static belongsTo = [basicProduct: BasicProduct]

    Date dateCreated 
    Date lastUpdated 


    static constraints = {
            title(blank: false, unique: true)
    }

    static mapping = {
        autoTimestamp true
      }

}
```

In my `Bootstrap.groovy` I have the following :

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product1", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:5.0).save(failOnError: true)
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product2", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:75.0).save(failOnError: true)
         new BasicProduct(title: "Product3", description:"blblblblbalablablalbalbablablablablblabalalbllba", price:50.0).save(failOnError: true)

         new Tag(basic_product_id: 1 ,title: "analysis").save(failOnError: true)


         println "initializing data..."
    }
```

However I get an exception:

```
|Running Grails application
context.GrailsContextLoader Error initializing the application: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.testapp.Product.Tag' on field 'basicProduct': rejected value [null]; codes [com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable,tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable,nullable.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,nullable.basicProduct,nullable.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,nullable]; arguments [basicProduct,class com.testapp.Product.Tag]; default message [Die Eigenschaft [{0}] des Typs [{1}] darf nicht null sein]
grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.testapp.Product.Tag' on field 'basicProduct': rejected value [null]; codes [com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.error,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.error,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.basicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct.nullable,tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.basicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,tag.basicProduct.nullable,nullable.com.testapp.Product.Tag.basicProduct,nullable.basicProduct,nullable.com.testapp.Product.BasicProduct,nullable]; arguments [basicProduct,class com.testapp.Product.Tag]; default message [Die Eigenschaft [{0}] des Typs [{1}] darf nicht null sein]
    at BootStrap$_closure1.doCall(BootStrap.groovy:20)
    at grails.util.Environment.evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock(Environment.java:308)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForEnvironment(Environment.java:301)
    at grails.util.Environment.executeForCurrentEnvironment(Environment.java:277)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

Any recommendation how to add a Tag for every product into my table?

I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using

```
new Tag(basic_product_id: 1...
```

Try doing something along the lines of

```
BasicProduct basicProduct1 =  new BasicProduct(title: "Product1", ...

...

new Tag(basicProduct: basicProduct1...
```